# Float Range with Regex in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Can someone help me to filter input in range 0.00 - 4.00

```
<input id="test" name="test" type="text" maxlength="4" required>

<script>
$('#test').on('change keyup', function() {
    var test = $(this).val().replace(/[^0-4\.]/g, '');

    $(this).val(test);
});
</script>
```

True :

- 0.00
- 1.90
- 4.00

False :

- 123
- 4.01
- 12.2

Update :

I mean, i don't want user typing something except 0.00 - 4.00. That why i need `on keyup` and `$(this).val().replace()`

Comment: Simply parse it as a number and compare it with `<` and `>`. Why are you trying to do this with regex?

Answer (score 2):

Regular expression is over complicating the task. You can achieve the same result by simply parsing the value of the text field with `String.prototype.parseFloat`

```js
$('#test').on('change keyup', function() {
  var $this = $(this)
  var test = parseFloat($this.val())
  // test if the value is between your range
  if (test > 0 && test <= 4) {
    $this.addClass('pass')
  }
  else {
    $this.removeClass('pass')
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  border: 2px solid red; 
}

input.pass {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" name="test" type="text" maxlength="4" required>
```